# Bitcoin payment delayed

Tags: address, unconfirmed-transactions

I recently encountered a situation involving a Bitcoin transaction, and I'm seeking some clarification and advice. I provided someone with my Bitcoin address to receive payment, but I haven't received the funds yet. The sender claims to have sent the money, but it has been two days since the transaction was initiated.

To support their claim, the sender provided me with a screenshot showing a different Bitcoin address than the one I provided. They explained that the address can change during the transaction processing. I'm a bit confused and uncertain about whether this is true or not. Should the address remain the same as the one I initially provided?

Is there any way to verify the legitimacy of the transaction using the provided transaction ID or other means? What can I tell based on the given screenshot?

Thank you in advance for your assistance and guidance.

[image: here is the picture I was send as proof]

Comment: You mentioned a "support", what kind of support is it? Is it a legit exchange, or what happened?

Comment: No, it's just not an exchange but a guy I know.

Answer (score 1):

> **They explained that the address can change during the transaction processing. I'm a bit confused and uncertain about whether this is true or not. Should the address remain the same as the one I initially provided?**

Addresses do not change *during transaction processing*.

Modern wallets will create a new receiving address for each new transaction - so whenever you click the "Receive" button (or similar) in a wallet, your wallet generates a new address. However it still keeps track of all previously created addresses. Money sent to old addresses will still be received.

Again, this does not mean addresses change during a transaction. The receiving address you gave the other party is the address that will be used.

It is possible the sender's wallet may show the sender the sending address, not the receiving address.

As others have said, the best way to proceed is to check the transaction-identifier (TXID) at the bottom of the screenshot in any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) - one of the "outputs" of the transaction should show your address (the one you gave the sender) and the expected amount in BTC. You will have to be careful when retyping the TXID from that image.

It is probable that the TXID shown is one in which the sender received some money and that they are not being truthful with you or are incompetent. They should tell you the TXID of the transaction that they created to send money to you. If they can't do this you should not accept that they have sent any money.

Answer (score 0):

If you provided an address to someone (?) and they sent a transaction to a different address, then they didn't send it to you, it's that easy.

To verify the screenshot, just open any "Bitcoin explorer" webpage and search for your address. If there is an incoming transaction, you'll see there. You can also search for the provided txid, and check if the receiving address is yours.

Comment: How do I get the txtid?

Comment: Ask the sender or search for incoming transactions for your address. I can also see a long hex at the bottom of the screenshot, it can be the txid.

Answer (score 0):

When the sender sends BTC to an address, they have transaction ID that can be used to verify the send operation.

So ask for this transaction ID and look up its details in a block explorer (blockchain.com/explorer will do). If you don't see your address as the recipient, then there's enough foundation to claim your sender not telling the truth.